# Dart: How Can I use multiple instances of the same singleton for different purposes?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a class that is used to play sound using **audioplayers**.I have the below code where the function **clickSound** just plays a simple button click sound audio without any loop and the function **loopSound** plays music in a loop.However I am unable to play both at the same time in case the music is playing and I want to click a button for example.How can I implement that functionality with the below code?

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:biblequiz/services/preferences.dart';

class AudioService {
  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  static final AudioService instance = AudioService._();

  AudioService._() {
    this.player.setVolume(1.0);
  }

  void clickSound() async {
    await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/click.mp3'));      
  }

  void loopSound() async {
      player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
      await player.play(AssetSource('sounds/music.wav'));
  }

  void stopLoop() async {
    await player.stop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Multiple singletons" by itself sounds mutually exclusive. While nothing is blocking you from creating another `static` `instance` under a different name, in your case, you may want to rethink your app's architecture. For example, you may want to use multiple instances of your `AudioService` instead of a singleton and **inject** the necessary instance of that `AudioService`.

Comment: Yeah I kind of felt it was kind of contradictory but regarding your second option I need the music playing to be controlled(start and stop) from different places in the app which is why I created a singleton for the music and then realized I could not play multiple sounds at the same time.